# how to access Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar using puppeteer?

Tags: dart, automation, puppeteer

my code :

```
final searchMenu = await myPage.waitForXPath('//*[@id="MenuBar1"]/li[4]/a');
  searchMenu.hover();

  final outClaims = await myPage.waitForXPath('//*[@id="MenuBar1"]/li[4]/ul/li[2]/a');
  outClaims.click();
```

error text :
Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement.

my code work just fine by selecting the search menu and makes its option visible for the user as in picture1.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKtmG.png)

[html code while search menu is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3r1F.png)

[html code when the search menu is not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfY5r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with your xpath. Try this

//ul[@class='MenuBarSubmenuVisible']//a[contains(text(), 'Out Claims')]

Comment: thank you! I really need to sharpen my html